# Drop all messages from queue when status = 0

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have a queue with a number of messages with status = 0.  The queue had retention turned on and the conversations were not properly ended.  I'd like to clean those messages out.

Receive does not get messages with status = 0, so I can't simply loop over the queue, receiving messages and ending the conversation as I go.  Is there any way I can remove these messages without dropping and recreating the queue?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER QUEUE ... WITH RETENTION = OFF;
```

Messages with status 0 are messages that were already received and are being retained. This happens because an authorized administrator has enabled retention on the queue, for whatever purposes. See [Message Retention](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171579(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Messages in a queue that are ready to be received have a status of 1. The RECEIVE statement returns messages that show a status of 1. After the RECEIVE statement returns a message, it sets the status to 0 and leaves the message in the queue if message retention is on.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear in the question that I understand how those messages made it into the queue in that state.  I'm curious how to remove them.  I have full control over the queue and can even drop it, but I'm curious if it's possible to remove these messages without having to fully recreate the queue.

Comment: My answer addresses exactly that question. Turning off retention will remove the messages. BTW the fact that the messages are there may also indicate that you are not properly issue END CONVERSATION.